# Javascript weird date behavior on 2017-03-26. Can't increment one day. Why?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

What is going on with the snippet below? I'm trying to build an array of strings as dates starting from a day in the past. I'm able to do it for the whole 2019 year for example. But when I start in `2017-01-01` somehow I CANNOT increment the date past `2017-03-26`.

I can increment `2017-03-27` to `2017-03-28` without a problem. Why is this happening?

```js
const currentDay = "2017-01-01";
const nextDay = new Date(new Date(currentDay).setDate(new Date(currentDay).getDate() + 1)).toISOString().split("T")[0];

console.log('currentDay: ' + currentDay);
console.log('nextDay: ' + nextDay);

const currentDay2 = "2017-03-26";
const nextDay2 = new Date(new Date(currentDay2).setDate(new Date(currentDay2).getDate() + 1)).toISOString().split("T")[0];

console.log('currentDay2: ' + currentDay2);
console.log('nextDay2: ' + nextDay2 + '<------ DOES NOT INCREMENT');

const currentDay3 = "2017-03-27";
const nextDay3 = new Date(new Date(currentDay3).setDate(new Date(currentDay3).getDate() + 1)).toISOString().split("T")[0];

console.log('currentDay3: ' + currentDay3);
console.log('nextDay3: ' + nextDay3);
```

I don't think this is an issue with my environment, but anyway, here's what I'm getting:

[image]

Are you guys getting something different?

Comment: I get `nextDay2: 2017-03-27<------ DOES NOT INCREMENT`. Maybe timezone related? (no idea)

Comment: I get this in jsfiddle: `currentDay: 2017-01-01 _display:35:9
nextDay: 2017-01-02 _display:36:9
currentDay2: 2017-03-26 _display:41:9
nextDay2: 2017-03-26<------ DOES NOT INCREMENT _display:42:9
currentDay3: 2017-03-27 _display:47:9
nextDay3: 2017-03-28`

Comment: My guess - daylight savings.

Comment: It seems to be daylight saving time / timezone related. How can I solve this?

Comment: @jared You can run Stack Snippets directly on Stack Overflow, no need to paste code into JSFiddle that's already runnable here

Comment: Any ideas how can I get past this?

Comment: this works `const currentDay2 = "2017-03-26";
const nextDay2 = new Date(new Date(currentDay2).setDate(new Date(currentDay2).getDate() + 1));`

Comment: I'd check out https://momentjs.com/ it's pretty lightweight.

Comment: The easiest is to just set the time to `12:00:00` - so it doesn't matter if you increment or decrement the hours.

Comment: Also your way of advancing to the next day is WAY more overcomplicated than it needs to be: `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)`

Comment: The fundamental issue is that dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD are parsed as UTC, but you are printing dates using local dates. So if you're in a timezone west of Greenwich, 2017-03-26 UTC is sometime the day before locally. So when you add 1 day and see the local date, it's still the 26th.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Since you are working with UTC format dates, and you want to ignore
>   local timezone changes such as daylight savings time, you should
>   always use getUTCDate() and setUTCDate(). UTC has no daylight savings.

This is a duplicate of the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38697372/6536335).

It's working properly on my side.

[image]

Comment: If it's a duplicate, then you should flag it as such, instead of posting an answer to point it out.

Comment: @VLAZ maybe... but i'd rather like to care the question.

Comment: The duplicate system is here to *resolve questions*. If there is an answer somewhere, it's more beneficial for everyone to have the answers in a common place, instead of fragmenting the knowledge across different pages. And everyone includes the OP as well as anybody who would stumble upon this after searching.

Comment: UTC is not a format, you might mean ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 1):

It is long code to make comment, so decided to make an answer:

```js
const currentDay2 = "2017-03-26";
let [y,M,d] = currentDay2.split(/[-]/);
const nextDay2 = new Date(y, (+M - 1), ++d).toISOString();
console.log(nextDay2);
```

It looks like [Date.Parse() parsed incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results).